# Woocommerce Cart/Checkout Notification when shipping to is not The Netherlands

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

For a client of mine I'm developing a webshop using WooCommerce.

When the total order weight is more than 30Kg and/or when the shipping address is not the Netherlands the user needs to contact the owner of the webshop for shipping rates.

For the first condition (order is more than 30Kg) I have created the following in my functions.php to display a notification message at the cart and checkout page:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_childtheme_scripts', 1000);

// Max weight check
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items','check_cart_weight');

function check_cart_weight(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $weight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
    if( $weight > 30 && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ){
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'The total weight of your order is %sKg. Please <a href="http://www.link-to-webshop.nl/en/contact/">contact us</a> for shipping rates for orders above 30Kg.', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ) );
    }
    elseif( $weight > 30 && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl' ){
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Het totale gewicht van uw bestelling bedraagt %sKg. Voor de verzendkosten van bestellingen van boven de 30Kg dient u <a href="http://www.link-to-webshop.nl/contact/">contact</a> met ons op te nemen.', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ) );
    }
}
```

So that works like a charm. But the problem is that I don't know how to create another notification message at the cart and checkout page when the user has selected any other country to ship to than The Netherlands.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with plugins?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/oik-weightcountry-shipping/

There is an official plugin from woothemes, but it's pricey

http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-conditional-shipping-and-payments/